# If $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ with period 2$\pi$ then $f$ can be approximated by a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-series

Question in more precise format:

**If $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$ with period 2$\pi$ and if $\epsilon>0$, then there is a trigonometric polynomial $P$ such that $|P(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all real $x$.**

Given: A trigonometric polynomial is a finite sum of the form $$ P(x) = a_o + \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx) $$ where $x$ is real and $a_0,a_1...a_N,b_1,...b_N$ are complex numbers

Hint given: Identifying $x$ and $x+2\pi$ regard 2$\pi$-periodic functions on $\Bbb R$ as functions on the unit circle $\Bbb T$ by means of the mapping $x\to e^{ix}$.

*I am just starting with the subject and would thus like to see a rigorous proof of this so as to get acquainted with the proof methodology.*

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: You want $x\to e^{ix}.$

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n (A_j\cos jx+B_j\sin jx)$ where $A_j,B_j$ are the Fourier co-efficients of $f$.  Using elementary Fourier-series methods it is surprisingly easy to prove a result of Fejer: If $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous with period $2\pi$ then $ \frac {1}{M+1}\sum_{n=0}^M f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$ as $M\to \infty .$